# How can I change the margin-left styling (responsive) while being viewed on smaller resolutions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The "marginleft:-13%" works best in 1200px+, but when being viewed on a tablet or phone, I need the margin-left changed to -52% and -9% respectively. I am having difficulty doing this. Im running bootstrap 2.3.2 on Windows.

reference URL is [solanosprinklers.net](http://solanosprinklers.net)

```
 <%= form_for @customer, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal',:style =>'margin-left:-13%'} do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :cust_fname, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"First Name" %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :cust_lname, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"Last Name" %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :cust_phone, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"Phone" %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :cust_email, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"Email" %>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.radio_button :cust_property,'Residential', :class => 'radio_button' %> Residential
          <%= f.radio_button :cust_property,'Commercial', :class => 'radio_button' %> Commercial
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_area :cust_notes, :class => 'text_area', :placeholder =>"How can we help ?" %>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="">
        <%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn btn-primary',:style => "background:green; margin-left:50%" %>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

here is the bootstrap_and_overrides.css file

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";

.hero-unit{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}
body {
    padding-top: 41px;
}

.span12 {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0px;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;
}
.form-horizontal{
  /* text-align:right; */
  text-align:left;

}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #new_customer { margin-left:-52% !important; }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
    #new_customer { margin-left:-9% !important; }
}


@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";




// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";

// Glyphicons
//@import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #new_customer { margin-left:-52%; }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #new_customer { margin-left:-9%; }
}
```

Comment: Ok , What would yourselector be for my form ?

Comment: Derek thanks for your help, but  would anyone know what yourselector would be ?

Comment: `yourselector` is the [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) for the element on which you want the margin.

Comment: In my case would it be @customer , since I want it appled to the entire form ?

Comment: You can target your entire form with `#new_customer`. It looks like your margin is being applied inline, so you may need to use `!important` to override the inline styles.

Comment: Hmmm...no it didnt work. Not sure what i may be missing. That approach works with sass, correct ?

Comment: @ElMerroPero It would be fine with sass. Did you try using the `!important` rule?

Comment: Yes sir, I added the css file above for you to see.

Comment: @ElMerroPero I don't see the update on the site. It seems to still have the old CSS. Did you recompile your sass? It looks fine in your question, except I noticed `479px` should be `480px`.

Comment: Yes I was tesing it locally , but I just sent it into production. I used 479 as i just copied your code. Either way, it did not do anything. What else can i try? ive been going at this for days.

Comment: I still don't see the new CSS on the site. It is serving the old CSS.

Comment: I thiught I was able to see some adjustments happenkng locally,  but it did not show up in production on phone or ipad

Comment: So im thinking the max width setting s need to get bumped up. .....the ipad/tablet does not get as low as 767px and the phone doesnt grt as low as 489

Comment: Its responding locally on my laptop screen as I increase and decrease the window size, but not on ipad or phone in portrait view